# lost my network issue installation of docker in ubuntu 16.04 virtual box

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed docker-ce in Ubuntu 16.04 using the installation guide given on their official website. Immediately after installing Docker, the host machine can no longer connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Check Virtual box network configuration. Use **bridged adapter**. Which will allow sharing of host system NIC card.